# Checking out a specific file from a specific commit gives "error: pathspec filename did not match"

Tags: git, git-bash, git-checkout

I'm using git on Windows.

Say I want to check out, not commit fe4fd (abbreviated to make examples shorter) but specifically file foo.html from commit fe4fd.

According to the documentation I should be able to use

```
git checkout fe4fd foo.html
```

and that should work. Or possibly

```
git checkout fe4fd -- foo.html
```

because the dashes seem to be optional.

Anyway. I'm at the right directory.

If I do a `git status foo.html` or `git reflog foo.html` etc. everything seems normal and it knows the file is there.

everything looks normal

I can do this:

```
git checkout fe4fd
```

and it works fine

I can do this:

```
git checkout foo.html
```

but I can't do

```
git checkout fe4fd foo.html
```

because every time I get

**error: pathspec 'foo.html' did not match any file(s) known to git.**

I've tried

- full paths from `C:/whatever` down to `foo.html`
- local paths like `./foo.html`
- including the enclosing folder, like `../myrepo/foo.html`
- enclosing in single and double quotes

what am I missing?

TIA.

**UPDATE**: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay got me to the answer. ElpieKay if you post your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct.

The answer is, *at the time of that commit*, the file *wasn't at that path*, because a parent folder had been renamed after that commit.

I figured this out by reading the documentation for `git log` and learning that it wouldn't follow a file's history through a path change unless you include the `--follow` flag.

I did what ElpieKay suggested, and the file wasn't apparently part of the commit. Which was wrong, because I knew it was. But the file I was trying to check out was, say `bar/foo.html` and that path didn't exist at the time of the checkout I was looking for. At the time of that checkout it was at `baz/foo.html`.

To prove this, I created a new `baz/` folder, `cd`'d to it, and checked out the file from the commit. This worked.

Comment: Does `foo.html` exist in `fe4fd`? Can `git ls-tree fe4fd -r -t  foo.html` print anything? If it prints nothing, the file does not exist in `fe4fd`'s tree.

Comment: Case sensitivity : isn't the file stored as "Foo.html" ?

Comment: @LeGEC Good idea but it’s definitely not a case issue. See the other commands which worked.

Comment: @ElpieKay I think you've figured it out. That particular commit number doesn't show anything, although that file was definitely in it. Folders were renamed and I don't seem to be able to go back before the rename. I can go back to the rename but not further than that.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `git checkout [commit] -- [paths]`, then the paths have to exist *in that commit* (to be more precise: in the tree referenced by the commit). If the file has been renamed since, you have to find the location of the file back then and use that.

Another possibility to update your working tree version of the file would be to use [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show):

```
git show commit:old/path/to/file.ext > new/path/to/file.ext
```

You can use `commit:./path/to/file` if you require paths relative to the current directory. Otherwise, the paths are anchored to your repository root.